# sql upadating table codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables `tbl_users(id,role_id,username)`, `tbl_roles(id,role_name)`

I have to update the `role_id` of the username in the `tbl_users` by fetching the id corresponding to the role_name = user from the role_name.

For this I am doing two queries first getting the role_id from the where `role_name="user"` from table `tbl_roles` and then setting the role_id where `username="username"` in the tbl_users.

My model function :-
I am doing two queries here and asking if this could be done in a single query.

```
function dropModerator($username) {
        $this->db->select('role_id');
        $this->db->where('role_name',"User");
        $role_id = $this->db->get('tbl_roles');
        foreach($role_id->result() as $value)
            $role = $value->role_id;
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET role_id='$role' WHERE username='$username'";
        return $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

Again, I want to do this because, this makes my program time slow while runtime and I want to do it in a single query in order to get the output fast.

Comment: Where is your problem? What do you want to achieve? And you pointed out you have three tables, but you reference only two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query for updating table in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754723/sql-query-for-updating-table-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in one query like this:

```
UPDATE  tbl_users 
SET     role_id = ( SELECT  Role_ID
                    FROM    tbl_Roles
                    WHERE   Role_Name = 'user' 
                    )
WHERE   username = '$username'
```